# Memory layout of the 4-bit integer type array

Tags: arrays, cuda, integer, gpu

How is the memory layout of int4 and int2 arrays? Suppose,

```cpp
int4 M[2];
M[0]=0xA;
M[1]=0x5;
```

What should I expect to see in the single byte containing M(0) and M(1)?   Is it 0xA5 or 0x5A?  I know that int4 is not a C/C++ type, but some compilers must be handling it because Nvidia and AMD GPUs support it.

Comment: All C arrays are laid out as a contiguous sequence of objects of the array's element type, starting with the object with index 0.  But the question seems to suppose that an array element can be smaller than 8 bits.  This is not the case.  All object sizes are an integral number of `char`-sized units, and `char` must be at least 8 bits wide to accommodate one of the allowed ranges of values for that type.  You might have an integer type with (say) only 4 value bits, but its *storage size* must still be at least 8 bits.

Comment: What do you mean by "single byte"? Int is a 32 bit type on the platforms you refer to, meaning that int4 is 16 bytes, and M[0] is 4 bytes, not one

Comment: On a standard linux install, the definition of the `int4` CUDA type is given in `/usr/local/cuda/include/vector_types.h`.  It is: `struct __device_builtin__ __builtin_align__(16) int4 { int x, y, z, w; };`  With that bit of decoding your question is now purely a C++ question.  If you don't know how to interpret that C++ code, you can ask a C++ question on SO, or at least tag your question with C++.  For the purpose of what you have expressed in your question (ordering) the `__device_builtin__` and `__builtin_align__(16)` directives can be ignored.

Comment: @talonmies, they are referring to a 4-*bit* integer, which seems to be a thing supported by some GPUs.  But as I was about to comment, the average C programmer is much more likely to interpret the type name `int4` to mean a 4-*byte* integer.

Comment: They are not referring to a 4-bit integer.  Please read my comment.

Comment: I did read your comment, @RobertCrovella.  But the OP's question can be understood only in terms of a 4-bit type -- this is how they can imagine that two array elements fit in a single byte.  That the CUDA API actually provides a type named `int4` comprising 4 `int`s certainly confuses the matter, but it is not directly relevant to the question.

Comment: For completeness: 1. later in the same file I referenced, the following typedef occurs, which has little bearing on the things being asked in the question: `typedef __device_builtin__ struct int4 int4;`  2. Similar statements applying to `int2`; it is also defined in the same file.

Comment: `int4` as understood by the CUDA compiler (OP specifically mentions the compiler handling that statement) is as I described.  Whether the OP is confused into thinking it is an array of 4 bit types is not entirely clear to me, but even if that is the case, reinforcing that idea is not what I would suggest.  Better to clean the slate and start from first principles.  Just my opinion, naturally, thanks for helping on SO!

Comment: @RobertCrovella, the OP is not confused about the CUDA API.  They are *ignorant* of it. They are talking about low-precision integers such as are [supported by Turing](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-turing-architecture-in-depth/).  Note well that that paper refers to all numeric data types in terms of their width in bits -- `INT32`, `FP32`, `FP16`, and, yes, new-in-Turing `INT8` and `INT4`.

Comment: And `INT2` (or `int2`, if you wish) fits that description? (I could also point out there is a case difference in the 2 naming systems).

Comment: I think the OP's `int2` is an hallucination. Again, the primary question is clearly about a data type that they think is 4 bits wide, and "Nvidia and AMD GPUs support it" is much better interpreted in terms of the native types of GPU hardware than in terms of CUDA, which is irrelevant to AMD GPUs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: No they are not. Those are very standard vector types for GPUs -- defined in CUDA, and Vulkan, and OpenCL, and HLSL, and OpenGL. And no, there are no 4 bit integers on any GPU platform I am familiar with

Comment: Meet [Turing](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-turing-architecture-in-depth/), @talonmies.

Comment: I meant to say a 4-bit integer type.  My bad.  I misused int4.  And I am ignorant of the CUDA API as @JohnBollinger wrote above.  @AbatorAbetor explained below that sub-byte elements cannot be accessed via the array notation `[]` which I think answers my original question

Answer (score 5):

The `int4` datatype in CUDA consists of 4 32-bit integers.

However, NVidia's tensor core wmma operations can process sub-byte elements, such as 4-bit integers and 1-bit integers which are packed in a 32-bit integer, but those subbyte elements cannot be accessed via `[]`. 4-bit operations are deprecated and removed in Hopper (sm_90). This is explained in the programming guide.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sub-byte-operations

> Sub-byte WMMA operations provide a way to access the low-precision capabilities of Tensor Cores. They are considered a preview feature i.e. the data structures and APIs for them are subject to change and may not be compatible with future releases. This functionality is available via the nvcuda::wmma::experimental namespace:

```
namespace experimental {
    namespace precision {
        struct u4; // 4-bit unsigned
        struct s4; // 4-bit signed
        struct b1; // 1-bit
   }
...
}
```

Following code prints the contents of a wmma fragment whose original data has the first byte set to `0b10100101` (0xA5)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <mma.h>
using namespace nvcuda;

__global__ void kernel(unsigned int *a, unsigned int *b, unsigned int *c) {
    wmma::fragment<wmma::matrix_a, 8, 8, 32, nvcuda::wmma::experimental::precision::u4, wmma::row_major> a_frag;

    wmma::load_matrix_sync(a_frag, a, 32);


    for(int t = 0; t < 1; t++){
        if(threadIdx.x == t){
            printf("thread %d, fragment.num_elements %d\n", threadIdx.x, a_frag.num_elements);
            for(int t=0; t < a_frag.num_elements; t++){
                int v = a_frag.x[t];
                printf("%d ", v);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    unsigned int* d_A; cudaMalloc(&d_A, sizeof(unsigned int) * 1024);
    unsigned int* d_B; cudaMalloc(&d_B, sizeof(unsigned int) * 1024);
    unsigned int* d_C; cudaMalloc(&d_C, sizeof(unsigned int) * 1024);

    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(1024);
    bytes[0] = 0b10100101;
    cudaMemcpy(d_A, bytes.data(), 1024, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<1, 32>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

The code prints `165` which is `10100101` in binary.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have stirred up a bit of a hornet's nest with your reference to data types named `int4` and `int2`.  You're quite right when you say

> I know that int4 is not a C/C++ type

But you may be making an bad assumption when say

> some compilers must be handling it because Nvidia and AMD GPUs support it.

, at least inasmuch as you think the types in question might map directly to C data types.

Definitely, C has no data types with a storage size smaller than 8 bits, and that's such a deeply embedded constraint that I think it highly unlikely that any C implementation will ever provide direct support for such a type, even as an extension.

I anticipate that host programs working with such data types will need to use a wider datatype for individual values or to pack multiple values into arrays of a wider datatype.  I do not foresee any C implementation in which the question makes sense as posed -- no two distinct elements of any C array share a single byte.  As for the kind of packing schemes I expect to see, the bit order those use will be characteristic of the toolkit performing the packing, which will presumably choose whatever makes the most sense for the GPU being supported.  Conceivably, it might vary between GPU vendors, and maybe even between GPU families from the same vendor.

nVidia's CUDA toolkit, among others, does provide a type named `int4` (and another named `int2`), but that `int4` is a `struct` representing a vector of four 32-bit `int` -- 16 bytes total -- not a 4-bit low-precision integer.  You can have arrays of that type, but the example code in the question makes no sense at all if `int4` is interpreted that way.

In other contexts, it's not that uncommon for `int4` to refers to a single 4-*byte* integer, though `int32_t` would be the language spec's spelling for that.  Of course, no bytes of an array of such are shared between two elements, so that does not lend sense to the question.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, it may be worth pointing out that CUDA's vector types are `struct`s with data members x, y, {z}, {w}. Most also have additional alignment attributes.